# Proof writing involving complements: $A' \subset (A \setminus B)'$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove: $A' \subset (A \setminus B)'$ where $A'$ is the complement of $A$.

Suppose $x \in A'$.

[Proof here]

Therefore, $A' \subset (A \setminus B)'$

How can one prove this theorem?

Comment: For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and [here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: start by proving that $X \subset Y \iff Y' \subset X'$.

Comment: Use this result along with the fact that $A\setminus B \subset A$ that you've proved in your previous question.

Comment: Suppose x∈A′.
By definition we know x ∉ A and A ∖ B ⊂ A. Then x ∉ A∖B. 
Therefore, A′⊂(A∖B)′. Um?